# Finding all paths between a set of vertices in a DAG

Tags: graph, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a  graph `G= (V, E)` that is:

1. directed,
2. acyclic,
3. non-weighted,
4. may have more than one edge between two vertices (thus, source and destination are not enough to determine an edge).

And given a set of vertices, let's  call them `vSet`; that contains a vertex `vRoot`; I need to find **ALL** paths `pSet` between `vSet` elements respecting the following:

1. any vertex that appears as a source for some path in `pSet` must be reachable from vRoot.
2. any path in `pSet` must has its source and destination from `vSet`, and must not contain any other vertex of `vSet`.

I've developed an algorithm similar to BFS, that starts from `vRoot` (according to 1 above),  grow each of the current paths with one edge per an iteration until it reaches another vertex `v1` of `vSet`; then store this reaching path and start growing new set of paths staring from `v1`.

Here is a pseudo code

```
output = ∅;
maxLengthPaths = ∅;
1. add all edges that vRoot is there source to maxLengthPaths
2. while size(maxlengthpaths) != ∅ do
  (a) paths := ∅;
  (b) extendedPaths := ∅;
  (c) foreach path p in maxLengthPaths do
    i. if (destination of p in vSet)
      1. add p to output 
      2. for each edge e that destination of p is its source
        A. add e to extendedPaths
    ii. else
      1. add p to paths
    iii. for path p1 in paths 
      1. for each edge that destination of p1  is its source
        A. extend p1 by a edge and add it to extendedPaths
  (d) maxLengthPaths = extendedPaths
```

Here are my questions:
1. Is this the best way to achieve my task?
2. I was trying to figure out its time complexity; I found that its exponential of pow(maxNumberOfOutGoingEdgesFormAVertex, maxLengthPath). Is this really the complexity?